# Refunding of payments made

Tags: fraud

I was scammed November 2017 by a woman called, Adele Johnson. I wanted to trade on bitcoin, but didn't had the experience to do it myself. She offered her help to trade on behalf of me. I paid R8000 into my Luno account where she requested all my registration details as well my wallet address. She made use of Tradeway Option Platform to trade for me. According to her my money growth to $50 000 and for me to withdraw this money I need to pay $7000. I told her I don't have such money, she got angry and blocked me. 
A man, called Artem Vladys told me he can help me to trace this money through interpol. He requested a payment of $300 and he assured me that will be the only payment I had to make; which I made via Luno, I bought him bitcoin worth $300 and sent it to the wallet adress: 154oDjBXc1wSzYncP6YwrU7a9duVGd3J3. He requested another amound of $200, I unfortunately refused to make another payment before I haven't seen what he did to assist me tracing my lost money. He got mad and he blocked me.
Both people said they work for bitcoin.
All the transactions shows in my luno account. Is there any possibility that I can trace this money? Is there not honarable people/organisation who can get my money back?

Answer (score 2):

> **Both people said they work for bitcoin**

Some people lie.

> **Is there any possibility that I can trace this money?**

Criminals often try to make that difficult for you. It is unlikely that anyone can trace exactly where your money went.

> **Is there not honarable people/organisation ...**

There are but

> **... who can get my money back?**

Part of the design of Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies is to make it hard to track transactions to real people.

What you have done is the equivalent of putting banknotes in an envelope and posting it to a post-office box address in a foreign country where such boxes can be rented without presenting any ID.

You should report the crime to your local police. You would be wise to assume your money is lost.